# Can my JDK and Weblogic be in different directories

Tags: java, weblogic, environment-variables, java-7

I have my java jdk installed here
     C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

And my Weblogic is here
     E:\bea

Do I need to run my JDK in the same `E` drive or not required?

Comment: it's not needed. check the weblogic scripts like setEnv.cmd that it points to the correct java home and you should be fine.

Comment: Did you even try it before asking the question? At least try before asking on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not required to be in the same drive. Just make sure your `PATH` is correctly set.